# How to identify and display images from a MATLAB .mat data file?

Tags: image, matlab, arraylist, structure, datalist

I have a MATLAB file (`xyz.mat`), and apparently there are image data in this file but I have very little experience with MATLAB and have no clue how to 'extract/open' them.

This is the only clue I have:

> The Matlab data file contains a structure "data" with a field "dataList" which is itself a structure array with one element per image.  So the first image can be found in data.dataList(1).img

After loading the file into MATLAB (nothing happened) and typing the command `data.dataList(1).img` (I got a huge list of numbers) I still get no image.

Any help/ideas?

Comment: welcome to SO. This is not an actual programming question though, and you haven't looked into images and images in MATLAB. A digital image IS an array (1D, 2D or N-D of numbers) depending on the representation and data. Try `imshow(data.dataList(1).img, []),` if `data.dataList(1).img` are 2D (check using `size`) to see this 2D array as an image (grayscale or color).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and sorry if I posted in the incorrect area. I tried the imshow function you posted and got a grey image!

Also when I tried size(data.dataList(1).img) I got the output:

ans =

   310   342

Any ideas of how to get the colored picture?

Comment: The size you got indicates that it is a grayscale picture and thus you cannot get a color picture out of it. A color picture is made up of 3 primary colors, Red, Green and Blue. If it were to be a color picture then the size would have been: `310 342 3`. The last 3 indicates that it has 3 color planes: R, G and B.

Comment: so then can I assume if it is a grey scale image that the numbers in the image's matrix is just some sort of intensity value? Determining the intensity somewhere from black to white?

Comment: Correct. `0` is black and `255` is white.

Comment: Great! Ok so another quick question I did "size(data.datList)" and got output: "11     20". Does this mean that I have 11x20 images? Also, is there a more convenient way to view these pictures without seeing each one separately? Thanks again for all of your great help!

Comment: @gracielaestrada I added an answer summarizing some of your above questions. However, if new questions arise, try to update your original post (title, concrete questions, generic problem) to make it more specific and useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If `data.dataList(1).img` are 2D or 3D (check using `size`), you can use [imshow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) to visualize this 2D array (grayscale), or 3D array (color) as an image.

```
im = data.dataList(1).img;
figure; imshow(im, []);
```

You can find the range of this image using `min(im(:))` and `max(im(:))` or plot the distribution of it's values using [imhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html).

To view all images as a rectangular montage look into [montage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html) function:

> montage(I) displays all the frames of a multiframe image array I in a
>   single image object. I can be a sequence of binary, grayscale, or
>   truecolor images. A binary or grayscale image sequence must be an
>   M-by-N-by-1-by-K array.

In effect, you can put a number of K images (of the same `M x N` size) in an `M x N x 1 x K` array and invoke montage:

```
for k = 1:K
    I(:,:,1,k) = data.dataList(k).img; 
end
figure; montage(I);
```

Comment: I am tyring to use immovie to display my images, but have been finding difficulty. Any ideas?</p>Also, is there anyway to make the movie with "image" instead of "imshow", because I noticed a difference in object resolution. My images used a higher scale than [0,255], it was a 12 bit camera!

Comment: @gracielaestrada it is better to have a new post for a new or different question. Did the answer helped on your initially posted question? SO is based on a specific question/answer format. State your problem clearly, what you tried and what you are trying to achieve. Look into MATLAB documentation for these functions first. Since people do not have access to your data, or problem, you have to help them-help you.